# Tamaño botones en vista para iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Tengo el siguiente problema. En la vista para iPhone el tamaño de los botones "Play" y "Replay" es el correcto, pero al pasar a la vista en iPad el tamaño de los botones no se hace más grande. Es decir, mantiene el mismo tamaño que en la vista para iPhone.

No asi con las dos labels que veis en las imagenes las cuales he modificado su tamaño para la vista en (wR - hR). Aqui si se hacen más grandes en la vista para iPad.

¿Por que ocurre esto? Es la primera vez que me pasa. Tengo apps parecidas y no he tenido este problema. el tamaño de los botones se ajusta automaticamente al tamaño de pantalla.

He probado de todo; mantener el ratio, meter ambos botones en Stackviews...

¿que puede estar pasando y como solucionarlo?

[image: Vista iPhone]

[image: Vista iPad]

Answer (score 0):

Si dices que ya haz usado los size class para que en caso que sea iPad crezca, entonces tal ves tendrías que modificar el aspect mode de la imagen para que se expanda al tamaño del botón.

Comment: Hola, no termina de quedar claro si lo que indicas es un comentario o un intento de respuesta. Si es lo segundo, quizás sería útil que añadieses algo más de información (y quizás algún ejemplo). Lee [answer] para más información.